# Simple syntax error while using arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This is a problem i ran into and I cannot find a solution for it. It almost seems like my eclipse is wrong about this. Can anyone point me why this will not compile?

For such a simple piece of code I do not have many options to try.

```
public class MapTest {

    int[][] map = new int[100][4]; // Syntax error on token ";", { expected after this token

    for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
        map[i][1] = i;
        map[i][2] = i;
        map[i][3] = 1;
        map[i][4] = 0;
    }

} //Syntax error, insert "}" to complete ClassBody
```

The whole concept is to create a map. Every int array should have x and y so I can later compare it to players coordinates + terrain type and npc type.

Comment: The loop needs to be part of a method or at least an initializer block. Since you probably want to just run that class it would need a `main(...)` anyways so put all that code in the class into that method.

Comment: The `for` loop has to be in a method... You have put it outside any method where no logic is allowed, class attributes and method declarations only. Surround it by some method, like `public void iter() { /* your code here */ }`.

Comment: Method is missing

Comment: On a side note: `i < 101` will produce an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException` since the array only has 100 elements with indices 0 to 99 (so `i = 100` would be the problem).

Comment: The problem is that your code isn't in a method.

Comment: Voting to close as typo

Comment: Thank you all for answering. The obvious problem was fixed <3

Comment: There is no need to update the title as "SOLVED". You can accept the answer proposed (if it match your need)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put your code in method body or initializer.

```
public class MapTest {

    int[][] map = new int[100][4]; 

    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 101; i++) {
            map[i][1] = i;
            map[i][2] = i;
            map[i][3] = 1;
            map[i][4] = 0;
        }
    }

}
```

Also your array have only `100` elements with indexes `0`-`99`, so `i < 101` will lead to error. Replace it with `i < 100`.